# How to properly do a T-SQL case statement in my code as shown below

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

```
declare @result as decimal(18, 2)

select 
    @result = sum(basepay)
    case @result 
       when null then 0.00
    end
from 
    dbo.tblPayments 
where 
    ClientID = 1 and month(paymentfor) = 1

print @result
```

I want to display the result as 0.00 if `sum()` method returns empty or null
but SQL Server throws an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.

Comment: What problem are you having, specifically? Your question doesn't really indicate what you want.

Comment: hi, just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

No need to check for is empty condition,sum will always return one value if to doesn't have atleast one not null

```
select @result = case when sum((basepay)) is null then 0.00
             else sum(basepay*1.0)
             end
from
table
where conditions
```

or simply

```
 select @result=isnull(sum(basepay),0) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` ignores `null` values. You can write as follows.

```
declare @result as decimal(18, 2) = 0.00

select 
    @result = COALESCE(SUM(basepay), 0.00)    
from 
    dbo.tblPayments 
where 
    ClientID = 1 and month(paymentfor) = 1

print @result
```

Example 1:

```
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(10,2) = 0.00
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT NULL A   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3.0 A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4.0 A
)

SELECT  @val = COALESCE(SUM(A), 0.00) FROM cte
WHERE 1 = 3
SELECT @val -- 0.00
```

Example 2:

```
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(10,2) 
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (A INT)
SELECT  @val = COALESCE(SUM(A), 0.00) FROM @Tbl
SELECT @val -- 0.00
```

Comment: If there are zero rows, this will still leave `@result` as `null`, since no rows are processed so no assignment occurs.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You mean that zero rows  without where clause? empty table?

Comment: Yes, if `tblPayments` contains no rows (or at least no rows that match the `WHERE` clause) then the assignment within the `SELECT` clause is never executed and so `@result` will still be `NULL` in that case.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Can you check examples.